# Get website html source with PhantomJS in Azure Web Job

Tags: javascript, azure, selenium, phantomjs, azure-webjobs

I am using PhantomJS and Selenium WebDriver to download the page source from a website with the following code:

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
//error occurs here
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
htmlCode = driver.PageSource;
driver.Quit();
```

Everything works fine in my local environment but gives the following error in an Azure Web Job or Azure Website:

> Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:50388

I get an equal error message when running Selenium with Firefox as an Azure Web Job or Azure Website. I already activated "Web Sockets" in Azure Web App configuration dashboard. But the error still occurs.

My goal is to get the rendered (javascript and ajax) page source of a website inside a Azure Web Job.

Comment: What is the content of web.config file? Especially webSocket part?

Comment: @Stanjer There is no webSocket entry in my web.config

Comment: Add it as <WebSocket enabled="false" />. Then try again. If you don't know where to add look Herr an example https://github.com/auth0/sharelock/blob/master/web.config

Comment: @Stanjer I have added the entry to my web.config but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error on my task and it was because I was hitting the cpu limit for the azure plan for my instance.  I upgraded from 'free' to 'shared' and it still did not work.  It worked after upgrading to 'basic'.  Maybe that will help...

This was the link that helped me:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1eb5e0fb-79b9-4f55-8345-7f50053c13c1/webjobs-no-consistnet-behavior?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview